# touchesEnded occasionally not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, touches

I've implemented the following event handlers in my UIView:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) 
    {     
        self.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSArray* touchObjects = [[event allTouches] allObjects];
    for(int i=0; i<[touchObjects count]; i++) 
    {
        touch = (UITouch*)[touchObjects objectAtIndex:i];
        curPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"begin = %f,%f",curPoint.x,curPoint.y]);
    }    
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint curPoint;
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) 
    {
        curPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"ended = %f,%f",curPoint.x,curPoint.y]);
    }
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
     //logging touches
}

-(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
     //logging touches
}
```

The problem is I occasionally do not receive "touchesEnded" (or touchedCancelled) events.  I always receive "touchesBegan" and "touchedMoved" events.

I have logging in these methods so I am 100% certain I am occasionally not receiving the "touchesEnded" (or touchesCancelled) events I am expecting.

multiTouch is enabled.

Does anybody know why this happens?  It is extremely important that I receive these events as I use these events to remove a subview(s).

Is there a work around for this?  Is it possible to query the view (or window) for the current touches?

Comment: It would be better if you showed us your *actual* source code, since it might contain a problem that your fake source code doesn't have.

Comment: Updated code.  Its really that simple.  BTW: iPhone 4, iOS 5.0.1.  Its easier to reproduce with multiple touches, but it will still happen occasionally with just one touch.

Comment: Is there anyway to query the UIView, UIWindow, or otherwise for the current touches?

Answer (score 0):

Your `touchesBegan:withEvent:` method is incorrect.  It says this:

```
NSArray* touchObjects = [[event allTouches] allObjects];
```

The problem is `[event allTouches]` returns all touches, not just touches in the starting phase.  So when the first finger touches the screen, you will log one `begin = %f,%f` message.  Then when the second finger touches the screen, you will log *two* `begin = %f,%f` messages, one of which is for the touch that you've seen before.

Your `touchesEnded:withEvent:` method properly enumerates just the `touches` argument, which contains only the touches in the ending phase.  So for a two-finger touch, you will log three “begin” messages but only two “ended” messages.

I'm not aware of any way to ask for the current touches outside of the touch-handling methods.

Comment: I'll try switching it over and let you know what I see.  Thanks.

Comment: Still the same behavior.  Frequently I don't receive touchesEnded or touchesCancelled for the corresponding touchesBegan.  It can be pretty simple.  I touch the screen, it logs the begin touch, I lift my finger, touchesEnded is not called.  Its far more frequent with multiple touches, but it can occur even with a single touch.  It is absolutely imperative that I know when the user is no longer touching the screen.  Is the gesture recognizer code more stable? Where are these events going if my view isn't receiving them?

Comment: I know I'm not the only one seeing this, a simple google will tell you this. If I can't get the current touches via query is there a way I can tell the system to reevaluate the touches and resend them?

Comment: Is it possible the framework doesn't send them because they are "stale"?  If so, is it possible to tell the system to send events, even if the timestamps are too old?

Comment: I'm getting the same problem, PleaseHelp, its infuriating. I also need to know when there are *no more touches* and maintaining a count is not reliable *at all* with this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

have you thought to use `- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` instead?

Answer (score 0):

i have same issue, add shouldBegin delegate fixed the issue

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
```